# Interpolation with exact inverse

Tags: inverse, interpolation, inverse-function

I need to interpolate tabulated data for a simulation model, see screenshot for a simplified example (Yes, screenshot is from Excel, but the actual simulation would be programmed in [Modelica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modelica)). This is easy, and there are many ways to do it, e.g. the blue line uses linear interpolation, orange line uses cubic interpolation.

[image]

But sometimes I will need the exact inverse of the interpolated data. If I used linear interpolation, it is easy to get the exact/analytic inverse by just swapping the columns in the data table. But I also need the segments to be connected in a C² or C³ smooth way, so I would prefer to use e.g. cubic interpolation or Akima splines.

How can I interpolate my data in a smooth AND invertible way? My data is strictly monotonous, values are finite and continuous, a unique inverse exists. It seems the aspect of inverting interpolation by just swapping the columns is not discussed in any paper or book I read so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Steffen-splines to do it, they are monotonicity-preserving, smooth, and invertible, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.02145. Maybe other monotonicity-preserving splines do the same (Fritsch-Butland), this was the first reference I found.

Answer (score 1):

You have $n$ sorted data points $(x_i,y_i)$

What I would suggest is to use parametric splines, that is to say
$$x=f(i) \qquad \text{and} \qquad y=g(i)$$  This is simple and very efficient in both directions.

Just have a look [here](https://cse.engineering.nyu.edu/%7Emleung/CS3734/s03/ch07/cubicSplineParametric4.pdf).

Comment: The resulting curve won’t necessarily be monotone, so not invertible.